# What is the best way to implement one to many image field

Tags: django, django-models

I have multiple models "Foo,Foo1,Foo2". I want to add multiple images to each of them. What is the best way to implement one to many image field here ?

```
class Foo(models.Model)
     images = models.OneToManyField('Image',null=True,blank=True)
 class Foo1(models.Model)
     images = models.OneToManyField('Image',null=True,blank=True)
 class Foo2(models.Model)
     images = models.OneToManyField('Image',null=True,blank=True)
class Image(models.Model)
     name = models.TextField()
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_photo_storage_path,null = True, blank = True)
```

Is this a good way to do it ? Or is there a better way for this. I am using django 1.5.

Comment: Is this a one-to-many or many-to-many question? Your title says one thing, but your text says another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion using `ManyToManyField` seems fine, yes.

One small comment: why is `Image.image` defined with `null=True, blank=True`? Surely an `Image` is only valid if there's an actual `Image`?